# Obj renderer nlack with Three.js (on some laptop)

Tags: javascript, three.js, renderer

I'm using Three.js to build a watch in 3D (with all the parts separately).
Most of the parts are built from a SLT file, two of them (strap ans case) are built from a OBJ file converted by using Blender.

All the part render perfectly on my laptop (on chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 m).
But on a other laptop (same browsers same version), the case and the strap are diplayed without the texture (UV mapping). I've tried to juste set color but these elements still stay black.

By the way, the same problem happends on mobile.

Test color:
var color = new THREE.Color(0xff0000);
mesh.material.color = color;

image on this link:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6526

Ty :)

Comment: are your textures powers of 2?

Answer (score 0):

If color not display on object try with

```
           mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Plus also check whether your material is not instanceOf THREE.MeshFaceMaterial because it doesn't have property like material instead materials[index].
I assume you texture are power of 2. (focus on the color)